# Static executable segfaults if location counter is initialized as too small or too large in linker script

Tags: linker, ld, elf, static-linking, musl

I'm trying to generate a static executable for this program (with musl):

main.S:

```
.section .text
    .global main

main:
    mov $msg, %rdi
    mov $0, %rax
    call printf

    mov %rax, %rdi
    mov $60, %rax
    syscall

msg:
    .ascii "hello world from printf\n\0"
```

Compilation command:

```
clang -g -c main.S -o main.o
```

Linking command (musl libc is placed in `musl` directory (version 1.2.1)):

```
ld main.o musl/crt1.o -o sm -Tstatic.ld -static -lc -lm -Lmusl
```

Linker script (`static.ld`):

```
ENTRY(_start)
SECTIONS
{
    . = 0x100e8;
}
```

This config results in a working executable, but if I change the location counter offset to `0x10000` or `0x20000`, the resulting executable crashes during startup with a segfault. On debugging I found that musl initialization code tries to read the program headers (location received in aux vector), and for some reason the memory address of program header as given by aux vector is unmapped in our address space.

What is the cause of this behavior? What exactly is the counter offset in a linker script? How does it affect the linker output other than altering the load address?

Note: The segfault occurs when the the musl initialization code tries to access program headers

Answer (score 4):

There are a few issues here.

1. Your `main.S` has a stack alignment bug: on `x86_64`, you *must* realign the stack to 16-byte boundary before calling any other function (you can assume 8-byte alignment on entry).
   Without this, I get a crash inside `printf` due to `movaps %xmm0,0x40(%rsp)` with misaligned `$rsp`.
2. Your link order is wrong: `crt1.o` should be linked *before* `main.o`
3. When you don't leave `SIZEOF_HEADERS == 0xe8` space before starting your `.text` section, you are leaving it up to the linker to put program headers elsewhere, and it does. The trouble is: musl (and a lot of other code) *assumes* that the file header and program headers are mapped in (but the ELF format doesn't require this). So they crash.

The right way to specify start address:

```
ENTRY(_start)
SECTIONS
{
    . = 0x10000 + SIZEOF_HEADERS;
}
```

**Update:**

> Why does the order matter?

Linkers (in general) will assemble initializers (constructors) left to right. When you call standard C library routines from `main()`, you expect the standard library to have initialized itself *before* `main()` was called. Code in `crt1.o` is responsible for performing such initialization.

If you link in the wrong order: `crt1.o` *after* `main.o`, construction may not happen correctly. Whether you'll be able to observe this depends on implementation details of the standard library, and exactly what parts of it you are using. So your binary may *appear* to work correctly. But it is still better to link objects in the correct order.

> I'm leaving 0x10000 space, isn't it enough for headers?

You are *interfering* with the built-in default linker script, and instead giving it *incomplete* specification of how to lay out your program in memory. When you do so, you need to know *how* the linker will react. Different linkers will react differently.

The binutils `ld` reacts by not emitting a `LOAD` segment covering program headers. The `ld.lld` reacts differently -- it actually moves `.text` past program headers.

The resulting binaries still crash though, because the binary layout is not what the kernel expects, and the kernel-supplied `AT_PHDR` address in the aux vector is wrong.

It looks like the kernel expects the first `LOAD` segment to be the one which contains program headers. Arguably that is a bug in the kernel -- nothing in the ELF spec requires this. But all *normal* binaries do have program headers in the first `LOAD` segment, so you'll just have to do the same (or convince kernel developers to add code to handle your weird binary layout).

Comment: 1. Is this a linux constraint or a cpu constraint.

Comment: @factorial It's not a Linux constraint, it's an `x86_64` ABI constraint.

Comment: 2. Why does the order matter.

3. I'm leaving 0x10000 space, isn't it enough for headers? Why does it fail if location counter is set to 0x20000?

Comment: I tried linking with this script: https://gist.github.com/fctorial/90068e7ddc50b3097990d3d8c592ea49



I expected it to work but the linker fails with an error saying 'could not allocate headers'. The linker fails if the initial value of offset is less than `176`, which is `64 + 2 * 56 == SIZEOF_HEADERS`. If I add another program header. this minimum limit changes to `232 == 176 + 56`. Why does the initial offset value matter if I'm allocating a separate section for the headers? Both gnu ld and lld act in this way.

Comment: @fctorial I suggest accepting this answer and asking a separate question along the lines of "I am trying to achieve {your actual goal}. I am using linker script {link to your script}. I am getting {actual error}. How should I fix this?"

Comment: The question was about the effect of initial load offset on linker output, and an explanation of how exactly initial load offset works (last paragraph of the question). I expected the above example to work since it was constructed by following this answer, and the issue with this script is exactly the one in the question (initial load offset not working as expected). Thanks a lot by the way. The current answer was useful.